# How to get the number of posts that located in 2 specific categories at the same time in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, count, categories, posts

I have tried to use this code:

```
$terms = get_terms('translates_category', 'include=220,238');
```

But it returns an array with two separate objects:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [term_id] => 220
        [name] => Degrees of comparison
        [slug] => degrees-of-comparison
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 272
        [taxonomy] => translates_category
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 217
        [count] => 2
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [term_id] => 238
        [name] => Lesson
        [slug] => lesson
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 290
        [taxonomy] => translates_category
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 1
    )
)
```

As I can assume, it's returns number of all posts (count) in those 2 categories separately. But I need the total number of only the posts that located in both categories at the same time.

There may be 100 posts in first category and 10 in second but only 1 of them may be associated with both of categories at a time. And I need to count such posts.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to get total number as cat1 has 3 and cat1 has 1  `3+1=4` ?

Comment: I need to get the number of the posts that associated with two cateories at the time. There may be 100 posts in first category and 10 in second but only 1 of them may be associated with both of categories at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
function my_post_count($tax, $cat1, $cat2) {
    $args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $tax,
                'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms' => array( $cat1 ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $tax,
                'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms' => array( $cat2 ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
        )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    return $query->post_count;
}
echo my_post_count('translates_category', 220, 238);
```

Comment: Seems like it realy works! I'm not fully shure but I will test it with more posts in those two categories. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code, for this you have to make two portion for post i.e. one for each

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category' => 3 );


$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
setup_postdata($post); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Change the number of post and and category you want to display...

Comment: But I don't need to dislpay posts or categories. I need to get the number of posts that located in two categories

Answer (score 0):

You can paste this function in your `functions.php`

```
function get_post_count($categories) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_count = 0;
    $post_count_array=array();
    foreach($categories as $cat) :
        $catID=get_cat_id($cat);
        $querystr = "SELECT count FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = $catID";
        $result = $wpdb->get_var($querystr);
        $post_count += $result;
        $post_count_array[$cat]=$result;
    endforeach;
    $post_count_array['total']=$post_count;
    return $post_count_array;
}
```

Then call this function like

```
$posts_Cat_Num=get_post_count(array('plugin', 'php')); // these are category names
print_r($posts_Cat_Num); // Array ( [plugin] => 2 [php] => 3 [total] => 5 ) 
echo $posts_Cat_Num['plugin']; // 2
echo $posts_Cat_Num['php']; // 3
echo $posts_Cat_Num['total']; // 5
```

**Update** (from the comment I understood the question)

```
$q=new WP_Query(array('category__and' => array(220, 238))); // get posts for both category ids
echo $q->post_count;
```

Comment: It's not actually what I need

Comment: I asked you but now I got what you need.

Comment: For some reason it does not returns any posts in $q->posts. Even if I specified  'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'translates_category')

Comment: @NikitaGavrilov, I've tested it on my localhost and it works fine for me, anyways, you've already accepted the answer.